# Move Logitech Steering Wheel to angle using Force Feedback API

Tags: logitech-gaming-software

I'm trying to move a logitech steering wheel to a certain angle and keep it there using the Force Feedback API. I'm fine with absolutely any programming language, on any platform (Windows, Linux, macOS), if you could please provide me a few hints as to how I can go about implementing this.

Answer (score 3):

Force feedback support is actually in the Linux kernel in most distributions. I think it is best looking into the joystick application to control it. It features joystick control with force feedback support. You can install it on a debian-based distribution like Ubuntu using:

```
sudo apt-get install joystick
```

Next to applications to read controller positions (jstest and jstest-gtk) It features a couple of commands to control force feeedback like:

```
fftest
ffcfstress
ffmvforce
```

You will need to find out the port where your race wheel can be controlled on. You can do this by entering:

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices  |less
```

If connected, you should find your racing wheel with a proper name description and after that something like:

```
N: Name="Logitech Inc. WingMan Formula Force GP"
...
H: Handlers=js0 event9
```

Then you can use ffcfstress to let your race wheel oscillate. Fix it securely and enter:

```
sudo ffcfstress -d /dev/input/event9
```

You might need to specify the axis which has force feedback which usually only is on the wheel (not on the pedals)

```
sudo ffcfstress -d /dev/input/event9 -x 6
```

So I guess now you are interested in the source code, so you should do this to get it:

```
apt-get source joystick
```

You will find the source code here:

```
./utils/ffcfstress.c
```

You also might find this [documentation page about force feedback in the kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.13/input/ff.html) usefull:

Have fun, and please give your result back to the community!